# Class "Department" is mapped, but is not included in any persistence unit

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am getting this error and I have no idea the reason: Class "Department" is mapped, but is not included in any persistence unit.

I have two project.
One is In my persistence.xml, between  tag, there is only two lines:

```
<persistence-unit name="UserJPA">
</persistence-unit>
```

My class is:

```
package br.com.jm.user;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

//getters and setters
}
```

I am using EclipseLink2.1.2. Actually I can remove this if it makes the things easier.

Hugs,
Demetrio

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who finds this old question when searching for the "Class xxxx is mapped, but is not included in any persistence unit" error in Eclipse or RAD, a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862019/eclipse-3-7-entity-validation-error-not-in-3-6) question and answer has the solution that worked for me:

1. Right-click on the project and choose properties.
2. Select JPA
3. Select the radio button "Discover annotated classes automatically"
4. OK and wait for the project to finish building.

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

You need to specify what classes are included in the persistence unit in the persistence.xml file, like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="UserJPA">
    <class>br.com.jm.user.Department</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Now I have a new error message. I got "Required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder does not exist in selected libraries" when I tried to create a "New Dynamic Web Project" under the JSF Capabilities.

Thanks in advance. Demetrio

Comment: @Demetrio: I'm pretty sure that is unrelated to your JPA setup.  Unfortunately I have 0 knowledge of JSF.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on *persistance.xml* file in your project explorer

then click **Synchronize Class List**

it will generate your Class tags automatically

[image]

Comment: This was the case for me when I was trying to rebuild my workspace.

Answer (score 2):

The `persistence.xml` should have:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
     <persistence-unit>..</persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```